# issue with angular.isNumber

Tags: html, angularjs

can anyone tell why i getting issue with **angular.isNumber(Number("1s"))**

**Output I am getting is :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.x1 = "1s";
    $scope.x2 = angular.isNumber(Number($scope.x1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>{{ x1 }}</p>
<p>{{ x2 }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with weedoze

you need to replace the code as:

```
return angular.isNumber(Number($scope.txt).toString() == $scope.txt ? Number($scope.txt) : $scope.txt);
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.x1 = "1s";
        $scope.x2 = angular.isNumber(Number($scope.x1).toString() == $scope.x1 ? Number($scope.x1) : $scope.x1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>{{ x1 }}</p>
<p>{{ x2 }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [AngularJS doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isNumber)

> **Determines if a reference is a Number.**
>
> This includes the "special" numbers NaN, +Infinity and -Infinity.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.x1 = "1s";
  $scope.number = Number($scope.x1); // number = NaN
  $scope.x2 = angular.isNumber(Number($scope.x1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>x1 = {{ x1 }}</p>
    <p>Transform to number = {{ number }}</p>
    <p>isNumber = {{ x2 }}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: NaN is number.?

Comment: In this case, the function `isNumber` will return `true` if the value is `NaN`. Check the link to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.x1 = "1s";
    $scope.x2 = angular.isNumber($scope.x1);
});
```

I think this will work.

Comment: and character inside quotes "" is treated as stirng..
So if i give "1" also it treat as false.

Comment: Actually, you have to remove Number() and you have to use angular.isNumber() only. Because Number("string") returns NaN which is also a number. So angular.isNumber returns true.